# Mercurial: enable merge but forbid commit

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

How can I forbid commits and allow merges into specific branch?

eg. master branch can't be complete with a commit but can with merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow *only* merges in a branch, check in the hook whether every commit for that branch has two parents - and reject the incoming changes if it has only one.

Comment: Yep, that was the solution: 
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HookExamples#pretxnchangegroup:_enforce_the_stable_branch_to_contains_only_merge_commits_on_the_server

Answer (score 0):

Based on @planetmaker's idea 
I found a hook what can help me: 
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HookExamples#pretxnchangegroup:_enforce_the_stable_branch_to_contains_only_merge_commits_on_the_server